# User account type in registration form: buyer or seller

Tags: customer-group

I found an option in System->Permissions->Users. Admin can create roles for them. 
But how can I make a choice for a customer on registration form, who he wish to be: a seller or a buyer?

A seller will be able to add products on web site.
A Buyer - only purchase.

I googled some info that I should create attributes buyer/seller and display them in registration form. But attributes and roles are different things in magento as I understand. Should I associate them with each other or there's another solution?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you might be trying to build a marketplace type store. Have you checked out https://secure.unirgy.com/products/umarketplace/magento-multi-vendor-marketplace

It allows you to have vendors who log in and create products etc. It seems you are currently trying to customize the magento admin/frontend for something not quite intended out of the box.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I underestimated complexity of the situation, because I thought it would be possible to solve the issue within the confines of magento standard functionality. 
So seems like marketplace module is what I need. Thank you for your answer.